# Filter with IN clause in josson library

Tags: java, json

I need to apply filter using IN clause.

Library used: https://github.com/octomix/josson

My JSON file

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "motorSeries": [
        "UMT O (S)",
        "LX PLUS (S)",
        "XUMA DX (S)",
        "UMAI 100",
        "UMA (ULTIMA)"
      ],
      "CSDtemplateName": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "motorSeries": [
        "A",
        "B"
      ],
      "CSDtemplateName": "XYZ"
    }
  ],
  "sourceData": {
    "series": "UMT O (S)"
  },
  "filter": "data[$.sourceData.series in (motorSeries)].CSDtemplateName"
}
```

JAVA Code to filter data

```
String json = "{\"data\":[{\"motorSeries\":[\"UMTO(S)\",\"LXPLUS(S)\",\"XUMADX(S)\",\"UMAI100\",\"UMA(ULTIMA)\"],\"pumpModel\":\"CORA-12C\",\"CSDtemplateName\":\"CSD_CORA-100_12C.dxf\"}],\"sourceData\":{\"series\":\"LXPLUS(S)\",\"pumpModel\":\"CORA-12C\"},\"filter\":\"data[$.sourceData.series.in(motorSeries)].CSDtemplateName\"}";
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(json);

System.out.println(josson.getNode("eval(filter)"));
```

Output should be

```
"ABC"
```

But the code gives an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.isEmpty()Z
    at com.octomix.josson.FuncExecutor.applyWithArrayNode(FuncExecutor.java:216)
```

what mistake I am making. Can somebody help me to solve the issue

Regards,
Pranav

Comment: you got NoSuchMethodError from jackson lib. That usually indicates that you mismatched versions of your libs. Check what version of jackson your project is using and see if it's compatible with josson's version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@voismager is right. *Josson* is using the latest version of *Jackson* 2.14.1

BTW, the *Josson* expression is

```
data[motorSeries.contains($.sourceData.series)].CSDtemplateName
```

If you use `$.sourceData.series.in(motorSeries)`, `motorSeries` becomes the child node of `$.sourceData.series` which is not correct.